# Running jpa test inside Spring container

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, dependencies

I'm getting the following error when try to run test method:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType

As Google says the problem with dependency. I've got the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've added to maven the hibernate implementation of jpa:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run test in IntelliJ IDEA I can see the classpath:

```
-classpath "...C:\Users\sav\.m2\repository\javax\javaee-api\6.0\javaee-api-6.0.jar;...C:\Users\sav\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;..."
```

So both jars are present.

Please tell me, what can I do to resolve it? I cannot remove dependency on javaee-api cause I'm using the @Inject annotation.

Comment: some time the same jars are download from multiple dependencies, but the version is different. so that produce conflict between the jars an application make exception. so check all dependencies carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the scope of javaee-api from compile to provided, it resolved the problem.

Thanks.